# xcolor package; color multirows

Tags: tables, color, multirow

Consider the following table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \rowcolors{1}{gray!15}{gray!15}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \rowcolor{gray!50}
    Header & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4 \\
    Row1  & a     & b     & c     & d \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[0]{*}{Multirow1}} & a1    & b1    & c1    & d1 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & a2    & b2    & c2    & d2 \\
    Row2  & aa    & ab    & ac    & ad \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

What I am not happy with is the fact that "Multirow1" is now half hidden. Furthermore, instead of the colors `gray!15` and `gray!50` I want to use RGB values. Not sure how to do this though.

Comment: To define your own color in RGB simply use `\definecolor{somegrey}{RGB}{128,128,128}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose the lower cell is filled with colour after the `multirow` is created, hence covering up its contents. If you instead move the `multirow` to the lowest row, and use `-2` instead of `2`, it works better.

To define colours using RGB values, use either

```
\definecolor{<name of colour>}{rgb}{<red>, <green>, <blue>}
```

where `<color>` is in the interval [0,1], or

```
\definecolor{<name of colour>}{RGB}{<red>, <green>, <blue>}
```

where `<color>` is integers in the interval [0,255].

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{MyColor}{rgb}{0.8, 0.8, 0.8}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \rowcolors{1}{gray!15}{gray!15}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \rowcolor{MyColor}
    Header & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4 \\
    Row1  & a     & b     & c     & d \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & a1    & b1    & c1    & d1 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}[0]{*}{Multirow1}} & a2    & b2    & c2    & d2 \\
    Row2  & aa    & ab    & ac    & ad \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Torbjørn T.,
I have tried your code and my result is "Multirow1" on white background. (sorry for not sending image, but "I have not enough reputation to post image") What is wrong ? (I tried a lot of examples with \multirow and \cellcolor or \rowcolor and till now no success ...)

Comment: Recently on [texblog | because LaTeX matters](http://texblog.org/) a related blog post was published, that gives a short explanation: [Hidden text with LaTeX colored multi-row tables](http://texblog.org/2013/04/09/hidden-text-with-latex-colored-multi-row-tables/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do that with `nicematrix` (you need at least v. 5.13 of 2021-03-23).

You won't have the thin white lines that you would see with `colortbl` in some PDF viewers (for ex. SumatraPDF) at some levels of zoom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
   \centering
   \begin{NiceTabular}{rrrrr}
   \CodeBefore
     \arraycolor{gray!15}
     \rowcolor{gray!30}{1}
   \Body
   Header & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4  \\
   Row1   & a     & b     & c     & d  \\
   \Block{2-1}{Multirow1}
          & a1    & b1    & c1    & d1 \\
          & a2    & b2    & c2    & d2 \\
   Row2   & aa    & ab    & ac    & ad \\
   \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]