# Color in multirows

Tags: tables, multirow

I have a similar problem to that on the post [xcolor package; color multirows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89101/xcolor-package-color-multirows) with the following table. The four-row-cell containing the word 'HHeader' should be completely gray. I have tried to implement the solution reported in the aforementioned post but it does not work for me. How can I solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{ ll | C{2.1cm} | C{2.1cm} | >{\centering}m{2.1cm} | C{2.1cm} | }
        \hhline{~~|----|}
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{ } & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{VHeader}} \\ \hhline{~~|----|}
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{ } & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h1} & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h2} & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h3} & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h4} \\ \hhline{|------|}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{ } & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h5} & & & & \\ \hhline{|~|-----|} %\cline{2-6}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{ } & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h6} & & & & \cellcolor{red!40} \\ \hhline{|~|-----|}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{ } & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h7} & & & \cellcolor{red!40} & \cellcolor{red!40} \\ \hhline{|~|-----|}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{-4}[0]{*}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{HHeader}}} & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h8} & & \cellcolor{red!40} & \cellcolor{red!40} & \cellcolor{red!40} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You must add the color to each of the mixed cells, since unfortunately `\columncolor` seen not very useful for multirow cells. You need also change `\cline` instead of `\hhline` to avoid rules inside the multirow cell.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{ll | C{2.1cm} | C{2.1cm} | >{\centering}m{2.1cm} | C{2.1cm} | }
        \hhline{~~|----|}
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{VHeader}} \\ \hhline{~~|----|}
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{ } & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h1} & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h2} & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h3} & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h4} \\ \hhline{|------|}
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{red} } & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h5} & & & & \\ \cline{2-6} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{red} } & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h6} & & & & \cellcolor{red!40} \\ \cline{2-6} 
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{red}} & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h7} & & & \cellcolor{red!40} & \cellcolor{red!40} \\ \cline{2-6}   \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{-4}[0]{*}{\cellcolor{red}\textbf{HHeader}}} & \cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{h8} & & \cellcolor{red!40} & \cellcolor{red!40} & \cellcolor{red!40} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Now I have the cells in gray, but some of the lines can not be seen with the proposed solution (for example, the cells colored with red!40 color at right bottom position). That is the reason why I have used hhline instead of cline. However, my proposal does not work properly. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create that table easily with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc*{4}{wc{15mm}}}[hvlines,corners=NW] % NW : north-west
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!10}{1,2}
  \columncolor{gray!10}{1,2}
  \cellcolor{red!15}{4-6,5-5,5-6,6-4,6-5,6-6}
\Body
                     &    & \Block{1-4}{VHeader} \\
                     &    & h1 & h2 & h3 & h4 \\
\Block{4-1}{HHeader} & h5 \\
                     & h6 \\
                     & h7 \\
                     & h8 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

With the key `corners=NW`, the empty corner in the north-west is computed by `nicematrix` and the rules and the color instructions are not applied to the cells in that corner.

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

With combining `columncolor` and `\cellcolor`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{hhline}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{2}{>{\columncolor{lightgray}}l|} *{4}{C{2.1cm}|} }
        \hhline{~~|----|}
\mcc[2]{}   & \mcc[4]{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{VHeader}}    \\ 
        \hhline{~~|----|}
\mcc[2]{}   & \cellcolor{lightgray}{\textbf{h1}} 
                & \cellcolor{lightgray}{\textbf{h2}} 
                    & \cellcolor{lightgray}{\textbf{h3}} 
                        & \cellcolor{lightgray}{\textbf{h4}}    \\
    \hhline{|------|}
    & \textbf{h5} & & & &                       \\ 
\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-----|} 
    & \textbf{h6} & & & & \cellcolor{red!40}    \\
\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-----|} 
    & \textbf{h7}
        &   &   & \cellcolor{red!40}
                    & \cellcolor{red!40}        \\
\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-----|} \multirow{-4}[0]{*}{\cellcolor{lightgray}{\textbf{HHeader}}}
    &   \textbf{h8} 
        &   &   \cellcolor{red!40} 
                &   \cellcolor{red!40}
                    &   \cellcolor{red!40}      \\
    \hhline{|------|}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```