# How to color a cell of a table using multirow and center the cell content?

Tags: tables, color, multirow

I have checked for other similar questions. I followed the suggested solution in the question [Color in multirows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111294/color-in-multirows). After implementing this solution, I still have a problem.

I want to develop the following table:

[image]

I want to color specific cells, but I am using multirow, so I used the following code,

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[skip=5pt]{caption}   % Unifies the distance between caption and float
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[ht]
\center{\caption{\label{tab:grid} The Grid.}
\scalebox{1}
{{
\begin{tabular}{m{2.25cm} m{3cm} m{3cm} m{3cm} m{3cm}}
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{A}}}&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor{blue!25}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor{blue!25} \textbf{C}}}& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{D}}} \tabularnewline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25} \textbf{B}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \tabularnewline
\cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{D}} }& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{A/CD}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{B/CD}} &  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{CD}}   \tabularnewline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}   \tabularnewline
\cline{1-1}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{C}}} &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}  \tabularnewline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}   \tabularnewline
\cline{1-5}
\end{tabular}
}}}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

and here is what I got:

[image]

You can notice that I used two different methods for C and B. My questions are:

1- In case of C, I colored the first row of the two-row cell, inserted C, then colored the second half, so the color in the second half overlapped the C. To solve this, I colored the upper row, then the lower row, and then inserted B, which gives a better result, but now B is not centered in the cell, how can I do that?

2-  In both cases, the color overlaps the cell boarders. I could overcome the problem in the vertical lines around C and B by adding "|" in C and D to thicken the line, however, the horizontal lines above and below B and C disappeared.

Could ***colortbl*** provide a better solution?

Comment: never do `&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}` always `&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}` the rules are just on the right edge of each cell (except the first column) otherwise you get spurious mis-aligned rule segments on the left which is why your vertical rules have thick and thin segments. if using multirow and color you need to put the text in the _last_ row with a -ve row span so it overlaps the color rather than being covered. As for the last question, You are using colortbl already (xcolor loads that package)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but if I use &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} the color overlaps the vertical lines, that is why I use &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} to make it thick. Can you kindly provide a complete answer with the -ve row span example? This will be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to colour the cell in the first row, then put the content in the second row using

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{blue!25} \textbf{C}}}  %% note -2
```

as in

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{A}}}&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{blue!25}}&  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{blue!25} \textbf{B}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{blue!25} \textbf{C}}}& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{D}}} \\
\cline{1-5}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[skip=5pt]{caption}   % Unifies the distance between caption and float
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}   %% may be better to learn doing this
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[ht]
%\arrayrulewidth=1% %% this is how you increase the thickness of rules
\centering\caption{\label{tab:grid} The Grid.}    %% don't use \center{...}
\scalebox{1}
{{
\begin{tabular}{|m{2.25cm} |m{3cm} |m{3cm} |m{3cm} |m{3cm}|}
\cline{2-5}\noalign{\vspace{0.4pt}}     %% add this space and adjust suitably
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{A}}}&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{blue!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\cellcolor{blue!25}}&  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{blue!25} \textbf{B}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{blue!25} \textbf{C}}}& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{D}}} \\
\cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{D}} }& \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{4}{*}{A/CD}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{4}{*}{B/CD}} &  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{CD}}   \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}   \\
\cline{1-1}
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{C}}} &\multicolumn{1}{|c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}  \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}   \\
\cline{1-5}
\end{tabular}
}}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `hhline`, `colortbl` and  `makecell` it is possible  — and the syntax is a bit simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[skip=5pt]{caption} % Unifies the distance between caption and float
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[6pt]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{\label{tab:grid} The Grid.}
  \begin{tabular}{|m{.4cm}| *{2}{m{0.9cm}|}*{2}{m{0.45cm}|}}
  \hhline{~|-|-|-|-|}
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \thead{A} & \cellcolor{blue!25}\thead{B}&\cellcolor{blue!25} \thead{C} & \thead{D} \\
\hline
\multirowthead{1}[10pt]{D} & \multirowcell{2}{A/CD} & \multirowcell{2}{B/CD} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirowcell{2}{CD}}\\[-13pt]%
\cline{1-1}
\thead{C} & & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `multirow`, here' a stacking alternative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\xfrbox(#1,#2)#3{\fboxsep=-.5\fboxrule%
  \fbox{\makebox(#1,#2){#3}}\kern-\fboxrule}
\def\cfrbox#1(#2,#3)#4{\fboxsep=-.5\fboxrule%
  \fbox{\fboxsep=0pt\colorbox{#1}{\makebox(#2,#3){#4}}}\kern-\fboxrule}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\unitlength{1mm}%
\setstackgap{S}{-\fboxrule}
\centering
\caption{The Grid.}\medskip
\Shortstack{\xfrbox(6,6){\bfseries D}\\\xfrbox(6,6){\bfseries C}}%
\Shortstack{\xfrbox(12,6){\bfseries A}\\\xfrbox(12,12){A/CD}}%
\Shortstack{\cfrbox{blue!30}(12,6){\bfseries B}\\\xfrbox(12,12){B/CD}}%
\Shortstack{\cfrbox{blue!30}(6,6){\bfseries C}\xfrbox(6,6){\bfseries D}\\\xfrbox(12,12){CD}}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Frankly said, I do not understand the purpose for use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` in each cell of your table. With it you just, as I can see, only override the column declarations in table. Similarly is with use of `\scalebox{1}{...}`. As is not serve to any table feature. If you like to have table width equal column width, it is better to use `tabular*` or `tabularx` environment. But maybe I'm wrong.

The same  form of table you can achieve (behind the other above suggestions) simple with:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}    % it works also without option
\usepackage[skip=5pt]{caption}  % Unifies the distance between caption and float
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}      % http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{multirow}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table*}[ht]
    \caption{\label{tab:grid} The Grid.}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\arrayrulewidth=0.5pt
    \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}}
    \cline{2-5}\noalign{\vspace{0.5pt}}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}   
    &   \textbf{A}   
        &  \cellcolor{blue!25}  \textbf{B}    
            &   \cellcolor{blue!25} \textbf{C}  
                &   \textbf{D}                              \tabularnewline
    \hline
\textbf{D}              
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{A/CD} 
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{B/CD}   
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{CD}}    \tabularnewline
    \cline{1-1}
\textbf{C}  
    &   &   &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                       \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}ccccc}[hvlines,corners=NW,color-inside]
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
  & A & \cellcolor{blue!15} B & \cellcolor{blue!15} C & D \\
D & \Block{2-1}{A/CD} & \Block{2-1}{B/CD} & \Block{2-2}{CD} \\
C \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{\label{tab:grid} The Grid.}
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {Q[m,c,0.4cm]|*{2}{Q[m,c,0.9cm]|}*{2}{Q[m,c,0.45cm]|}},
    hline{1} = {2-Z}{solid},
    vline{1} = {2-Z}{solid},
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    rows = {2em},
    column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    cell{1}{3,4} = {blue8},
    cell{2}{2,3} = {r=2}{c}, % multirow
    cell{2}{4} = {r=2,c=2}{c}, % multirow and multicolumn
  }
    & A      & B    & C  & D \\
  \hline
    D & A/CD & B/CD & CD &   \\
  \hline
    C &      &      &    &   \\
  \hline
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]