# How can I format this table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, formatting

Table I created in Google Doc and want to create it in Latex

[image]

Comment: If you show us what it looks like, we might be able to imitate the look.

Comment: Aw man I thought I attached the picture. I'll have to wait 40 minutes to repost the question. Thanks.

Comment: @dante you can `edit` your question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/591657/edit

Comment: BTW never tried it but: https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/spreadlatex/218144906748

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://i.imgur.com/A1aWpII.png) one, or [this](https://i.imgur.com/y9SPd88.png) ?

Comment: You can use a combination of [colortbl](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.pdf) and [multirow](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/multirow.pdf) for this.

Comment: See also various approaches in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178976/how-to-color-a-cell-of-a-table-using-multirow-and-center-the-cell-content.

Comment: In order to avoid repetition, you might want to consider specifying the units once in the column headers instead of repeating them in every row.

Comment: OT: hmmm... `120*43/2=2.6kW`. Nice $\cos\phi$ or...

Comment: Thank you everyone!! This is super helpful!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate. But that aside, I think you should take a look at this site https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ it enables creating latex tables easily and (almost) efortlessly. For your simple case it will do

Answer (score 4):

You can construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In that environment, which is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of `array`), you merge cells both horizontally and vertically with the command `\Block`. The key `hvlines` draws all the rule, excepted in the blocks (created by `\Block`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
  
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!20}{1}
  \rectanglecolor{yellow!60}{8-2}{8-4}
\Body
           & \textbf{Voltage}                      & \textbf{Current}    & \textbf{Power} \\ 
A/C Unit   & $115~\text{V}_\text{AC}$              & 16 A                & 1.8 kW \\ 
Monitor    & \Block{5-1}{$120~\text{V}_\text{AC}$} & 2.8 A               & 94 W \\ 
Computer   &                                       & 7 A                 & 850 kW \\  
Laptop     &                                       & 4.5 A               & 1.8 kW \\  
Wifi/Modem &                                       & 12 A                & 1.8 kW \\  
Fans       &                                       & 1.3 A               & 158.4 kW \\  
Total      & $120~\text{V}_\text{AC}$              & 43.6 A              & 3.12 kW \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{document}
  
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{gray!20} & \textbf{Voltage}   & \textbf{Current}  & \textbf{Power} \\ \hline
        A/C Unit & $115\text{V}_\text{AC}$ & 16A & 1.8kW \\ \hline
        Monitor & \multirow{5}{*}{$120\text{V}_\text{AC}$} & 2.8A & 94W \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
        Computer &  & 7A & 850kW \\  \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
        Laptop &  & 4.5A & 1.8kW \\  \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
        Wifi/Modem &  & 12A & 1.8kW \\  \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
        Fans & & 1.3A & 158.4kW \\  \hline
        Total & \cellcolor{yellow!60}$120\text{V}_\text{AC}$ & \cellcolor{yellow!60} 43.6A & \cellcolor{yellow!60} 3.12kW \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}


\end{document}
```

The above table can be created like this. Its output is [image: table]
Also, visit my youtube channel [WP Galaxy](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCy0vz71kvXSJSmrzHGL77Rg) for LaTex Tutorials and subscribe to the channel.